# Setting hover duration for tooltip in ggvis

Tags: r, ggvis

Using set_options(hover_duration = 2000) works in this example:

```
library(ggvis)

mtcars %>%
    ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>%
    layer_points(fill.hover := "red") %>% 
    set_options(hover_duration = 2000)
```

However, the option does not appear to work on the hover of tooltips, such as this one:

```
mtcars %>%
    ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>%
    layer_points(fill.hover := "red") %>% 
    add_tooltip(function(x) 
        "<a href='http://www.google.com'>link here</a>", "hover") %>% 
    set_options(hover_duration = 2000)
```

Any ideas on how to make the tooltip stay up long enough to click the link?

Comment: A quick workaround is to replace `"hover"` with `"click"` in `add_toolip()`